# How to sort PivotTable (DESC values) with Interop.Excel (C#)

Tags: c#, sorting, pivot-table, excel-interop

How to sort a PivotTable with Interop.Excel and C#?
I got the generation of the PivotTable fully like I want it to, but struggling with the sorting...

Sorting should be done, that for "Title" and "SubTitle" the fields "Value2" are always having the highest descending values at the top per project.

Was trying around via Range.Sort() but without luck.
Tested way:
Defining a region (like I did manually in Excel for figuring out the way) with "C4" and the doing a Range.Sort on this. But then it is working for the first project, but not for all. Imho, because I set this only to the pointed range to one cell. The next try was to extend the range, but then I always got HRESULT exceptions with just an memory address given (useless for me).

The screenshots are showing the wanted sorting.

```
public void GeneratePivot()
{
    const string numberFormat = "#,##0 €;-#,##0 €";
    var missing = Type.Missing;
    string dataContext = @"DataContext";

    #region // Create Data

    var dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Project", DataType = typeof(string) });
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Title", DataType = typeof(string) });
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "SubTitle", DataType = typeof(string) });
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Value1", DataType = typeof(decimal) });
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Value2", DataType = typeof(decimal) });

    var row1 = dt.NewRow();
    row1["Project"] = "Project1";
    row1["Title"] = "Title1";
    row1["SubTitle"] = "SubTitle1-1";
    row1["Value1"] = 1000M;
    row1["Value2"] = 40000M;
    dt.Rows.Add(row1);

    var row2 = dt.NewRow();
    row2["Project"] = "Project2-1";
    row2["Title"] = "Title2";
    row2["SubTitle"] = "SubTitle2-1";
    row2["Value1"] = 100M;
    row2["Value2"] = 4000M;
    dt.Rows.Add(row2);

    var row3 = dt.NewRow();
    row3["Project"] = "Project2-2";
    row3["Title"] = "Title2";
    row3["SubTitle"] = "SubTitle2-2";
    row3["Value1"] = 220M;
    row3["Value2"] = 222000M;
    dt.Rows.Add(row3);

    var row4 = dt.NewRow();
    row4["Project"] = "Project3-1";
    row4["Title"] = "Title3";
    row4["SubTitle"] = "SubTitle3-1";
    row4["Value1"] = 32423M;
    row4["Value2"] = 430M;
    dt.Rows.Add(row4);

    var row5 = dt.NewRow();
    row5["Project"] = "Project3-2";
    row5["Title"] = "Title3";
    row5["SubTitle"] = "SubTitle3-2";
    row5["Value1"] = 2341M;
    row5["Value2"] = 4002000M;
    dt.Rows.Add(row5);
    #endregion

    // Create Workbook with Excel Interop
    Excel.Application excelApplication = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbooks workbooks = excelApplication.Workbooks;
    var workbook = workbooks.Add();

    #region // Create DataSheet
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet1 = workbook.Sheets[1];
    worksheet1.Name = "DataSheet";

    var colsCount = dt.Columns.Count;
    var rowsCount = dt.Rows.Count;
    Excel.Range range;

    // Create DataArray from DataTable
    object[,] dtArray = new object[rowsCount, colsCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colsCount; j++) { dtArray[i, j] = dt.Rows[i][j]; }
    }

    // Create header
    range = worksheet1.Cells[1, 1];
    range = range.get_Resize(1, colsCount);
    range.NumberFormat = "@";
    range.Font.Bold = true;
    range.Value = new string[5] { "Project", "Title", "SubTitle", "Value1", "Value2" };

    // Get an Excel Range of the same dimensions
    range = (Excel.Range)worksheet1.Cells[2, 1];
    range = range.get_Resize(rowsCount, colsCount);

    // Assign the 2-d array to the Excel Range
    range.set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, dtArray);

    range = worksheet1.UsedRange;
    worksheet1.Names.Add("DataContext", range);
    #endregion

    #region // Create PivotSheet

    Excel.Worksheet worksheet2 = workbook.Sheets.Add(After: workbook.Sheets[workbook.Sheets.Count]);
    worksheet2.Name = "PivotSheet";

    Excel.PivotCache pivotCache;
    Excel.PivotTable pivotTable;
    Excel.Range pivotData;
    Excel.Range pivotDestination;

    // Select a range of data for the Pivot Table.
    pivotData = worksheet1.get_Range(dataContext);

    // Select location of the Pivot Table.
    pivotDestination = worksheet2.get_Range("A1", missing);

    // create Pivot Cache and Pivot Table
    pivotCache = (Excel.PivotCache)workbook.PivotCaches()
        .Add(Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, pivotData);

    pivotTable = (Excel.PivotTable)worksheet2.PivotTables()
        .Add(PivotCache: pivotCache, TableDestination: pivotDestination, TableName: dataContext);

    // Style Pivot Table
    pivotTable.Format(Excel.XlPivotFormatType.xlReport2);
    pivotTable.InGridDropZones = false;
    pivotTable.SmallGrid = false;
    pivotTable.TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleLight16";

    // ROW FIELDS
    Excel.PivotField rowField3 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("SubTitle");
    rowField3.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    rowField3.LayoutForm = Excel.XlLayoutFormType.xlOutline;
    rowField3.LayoutSubtotalLocation = Excel.XlSubtototalLocationType.xlAtTop;
    rowField3.LayoutCompactRow = true;

    Excel.PivotField rowField2 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Title");
    rowField2.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    rowField2.LayoutForm = Excel.XlLayoutFormType.xlOutline;
    rowField2.LayoutSubtotalLocation = Excel.XlSubtototalLocationType.xlAtTop;
    rowField2.LayoutCompactRow = true;

    Excel.PivotField rowField1 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Project");
    rowField1.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
    rowField1.LayoutForm = Excel.XlLayoutFormType.xlOutline;
    rowField1.LayoutSubtotalLocation = Excel.XlSubtototalLocationType.xlAtTop;
    rowField1.LayoutCompactRow = true;

    // FILTER FIELDS
    Excel.PivotField pageField1 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Project");
    pageField1.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlPageField;
    pageField1.EnableMultiplePageItems = true;

    // DATA FIELDS
    int position = 1;
    Excel.PivotField dataField1 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Value1");
    dataField1.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
    dataField1.Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
    dataField1.NumberFormat = numberFormat;
    dataField1.Position = position++;

    Excel.PivotField dataField2 = (Excel.PivotField)pivotTable.PivotFields("Value2");
    dataField2.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
    dataField2.Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum;
    dataField2.NumberFormat = numberFormat;
    dataField2.Position = position++;
    #endregion

    // Close Excel
    workbook.SaveAs("Interop.Excel_Pivot.xlsx");
    workbook.Close();
    excelApplication.Quit();
}
```

[image: Screenshots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it!

```
var pivotLine = (Excel.PivotLine)pivotTable.PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines[2];
rowField2.AutoSortEx((int)Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, "Summe von Value2", pivotLine, 1);
rowField3.AutoSortEx((int)Excel.XlSortOrder.xlDescending, "Summe von Value2", pivotLine, 1);
```

**Hint:** Beware of, that given String "Summe von " is german language and  will be "Sum of " with Excel in English. ;)